# Compile error when trying to use worksheet variables with checkboxes in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, variables, worksheet

I'm having trouble creating Worksheet variables.  I can't work out why the code below doesn't work. It is fine when I don't try to use the worksheet scheduleSheet (i.e. when I use the commented out line instead), but gives a compile error, "member or data method not found" when I try to use a worksheet variable.  The problem seems to be when combining the worksheet variable with .CheckBox... as the rest of the code works (with scheduleSheet) when I comment out these lines (HT Olle Sjögren)

```
Sub Reset(sheetNamePrefix As String)
'reset sheet as blank
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim scheduleSheetName As String
Dim constantsSheetName As String
Dim summarySheetName As String
Dim scheduleSheet As Worksheet

scheduleSheetName = sheetNamePrefix & "Schedule"
constantsSheetName = sheetNamePrefix & "Constants"
summarySheetName = sheetNamePrefix & "Summary"

Set scheduleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(scheduleSheetName)

'With Worksheets(scheduleSheetName)
With scheduleSheet
    .CheckBox1.Value = False
    .CheckBox2.Value = False
    .Range("B4:G7,J4:L4").ClearContents
    If LastCell(Worksheets(scheduleSheetName)).Row > 10 Then
        .Range("A11:AA" + CStr(LastCell(Worksheets(scheduleSheetName)).Row)).Clear
    End If
    .Range("A11:A100").NumberFormat = "@" 'Clear
End With
With Worksheets(constantsSheetName)
    .Range("A18:A24").Clear
    .Cells(18, 1) = 2
    .Cells(19, 1) = 1
    .Cells(20, 1) = 180
    .Cells(21, 1) = 15
    .Cells(22, 1) = 360
    .Cells(23, 1) = 30
    .Cells(24, 1) = 40
    .Cells(50, 1) = 0
End With
With Worksheets(summarySheetName)
    .Range("C2:D6").ClearContents
    .Range("D8:D19").ClearContents
    .Range("D21:D25").ClearContents
    .Range("D27:D33").ClearContents
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As you have it, you don't have a space between your prefixes and "Schedule/Constants/Summary", should there be one?

Comment: I don't think the Worksheet is the problem. If I copy your code to a blank workbook and try to compile, there is an error on the line `.CheckBox1.Value = False` even if I add a checkbox to the sheet. Remove the checkbox-lines and see if the rest of the code works, and then figure out another way to clear the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks Olle Sjögren.  I commented out the .Check... and the rest of the code compiles and runs.  Do you know why it doesn't work with .CheckBox1.Value when using a worksheet variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that scheduleSheetName is a valid sheet name.  Put a break point after this variable is set and see if scheduleSheetName is a valid sheet name in your workbook.

Comment: The code doesn't compile, so you cannot run it and you will not hit any breakpoints... :)

Comment: The code works with the commented out "With Worksheets(scheduleSheetName)" in place of "With scheduleSheet"

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your checkboxes are named the same as what you have them named in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
.CheckBoxes("yourCheckBoxName").Checked
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have tried    .CheckBoxes("CheckBox1").Checked = False This gives me a runtime error 1004: method checkboxes of object _worksheet failed

Comment: Are you using ActiveX controls or just the regular Checkboxes ?

Comment: I think they are just regular checkboxes - Worksheets(scheduleSheetName).CheckBox1.Value = False works fine